# How to ensure specific WHERE condition evaluates first on view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, where-clause, openquery

Consider the following view:

```
create view x as
select 1 as [source],* from some_table
union all
select 2,* from some_other_table
```

When I run

```
select * from x where source=1
```

can I be sure that the `select 2....` query is not even executed?

The reason is that in my case, that one is an openquery with sluggish speed, which I want to avoid.

Comment: No it will compile the whole query. Put your query into a stored procedure and parameterize it. And do only the one select if source = 1 else union them

Comment: Well, I suppose that answers my question, formulate as such if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do stuff like this, but i dont know if that meets your other requirements you might have - Otherwise you can create 2 views.

```
CREATE proc dbo.usp_selectspecificquery 

@source int
AS

BEGIN

IF(@source = 1)
BEGIN

Select 1 as source, * from some_table

END
ELSE
Select 1 as source,* from some_table

union all
select 2 as source,* from some_other_table
END

exec dbo.usp_selectspecificquery 1
```